# How to have a UIImageview automatically stretch to 100% in Xcode with constraints

Tags: uiimage, interface-builder

I can't figure out how to get a UIImage to stretch the width of any given iPhone / iPad orientation and also maintain aspect ratio.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

so it'd be like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Name"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:self.view.frame.size.width topCapHeight:1.0];
```

that's not tested code, but it is to help show you the possiblity of using it

Hope that helps!